# Removing strings from other strings

Tags: python, if-statement

How do I remove a part of a string like

```
Blue = 'Blue '
Yellow = 'Yellow'
Words = Blue + Yellow
if Blue in Words:
    Words = Words - Yellow
```

That is what I thought it would look like?

EDIT:
I know thatit won't work I want to know what would work. Since you  cant use '-' in a str()

Comment: Use sets. `{'Blue', 'Yellow'}`

Comment: Is `Words` supposed to look like `'BlueYellow'` or `['Blue', 'Yellow']`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `str.replace` to exchange the text with an empty string:

```
Words = Words.replace(Yellow,'')
```

Note that this will transform:

```
"The Yellow Herring"
```

into simply:

```
"The Herring"
```

(the replacement will happen anywhere in the string).  If you only want to remove `'Yellow'` from the end of a string, you could use `.endswith` and a slice:

```
if Blue in Words and Words.endswith(Yellow):
    Words = Words[:-len(Yellow)]
```

Comment: is `str.remove` a syntax? because I read somewhere it was but it didn't work well?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `str.remove`.  That's not a method of the `str` type.  There is however a `list.remove`

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith -- Maybe they were talking about `list` objects?  There is a `remove` method on `list`s

Comment: What is the list function?

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith -- At this point, I'll refer you to the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).  Lists are a fundamental datatype in python and they're extremely useful.

Answer (score 3):

From a different perspective, you actually **can't** remove part of a string because strings (in Python) are **immutable** - they cannot be modified ([for good reason](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-python-strings-immutable.htm)). This means no assignments (`mystring[0] = 'f'`).

What you *can* do is build a completely new string with the specific part it of removed. This accomplishes the same goal.

This is actually pretty important, because it implies that

```
mystring.replace('m', 'f')
```

by itself, does *nothing* (note that there is no assignment - this just builds a new string, and then throws it away). Learning this concept of immutability (and mutability) is essential to learn - it will help you avoid many mistakes.

Comment: The point of immutability is worth addressing here.  I tend to assume that everyone knows that already so sometimes I forget to mention it.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Use [replace function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
if Blue in Words:
    Words = Words.replace(Yellow, '')
```

If Words is a list than you can do the following:

```
if Blue in Words:
   Words = [word for word in Words if word != Yellow]
```

Or the same but using remove:

```
if Blue in Words:
   Words.remove(Yellow)
```

Comment: which is just slightly different than `Words.remove(Yellow)` for a **list**